# how to redirect in the callback of a jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, callback, routes

my home page upon receiving the data does not redirect to login page.
here is the home page js:

```
$(function(){
    const submit = $('#submit');
    const save = $('#save');
    const email = $('#email');
    const username = $('#username');
    const password = $('#password');
    const userlogin = $('#Username login');
    const passlogin = $('#Password login');
    save.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/signup',{
            email:email.val(),
            username:username.val(),
            password:password.val()
        }, function(data){
            console.log(1)
            if(data.username){
            localStorage.setItem("username",data.username)
            }
            window.location.href(data.url)
        })
    })
    submit.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/login',{
            username:userlogin.val(),
            password:passlogin.val()
        }, function(data){
            window.location.href(data.url)
        })
    })
})
```

this is the routes.js file present on backend

```
app.post('/signup', function(req,res){
    var a = [req.body.email,req.body.username,req.body.password];
    Users.findOne({
       where: { email: a[0],
        username: a[1],
        password: a[2],
       }

    }).then(users => {
        if (users) {
        res.send({
            url:'/'
        })
        }
        else{
            Users.create({
                email: a[0],
                username: a[1],
                password: a[2],

          }).then(users => {
                res.send({
                    url:'/profile',
                    username: a[1]
                })
          })    
        }
    })
})
```

I need to redirect to /profile upon receiving a successful callback from the server.But right now the page doesnt load, however the username field is successfully stored in localstorage.
I believe it is occuring due to window.location.href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways.

First let me tell you what is wrong in your code,

You have to use,

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
```

As the notation you wrote is wrong

```
window.location.href(data.url) // this is wrong
```

[Window.location docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Now coming to alternative way,

You can specify the post method in your markup as well in the action attribute.

```
<form name="some_name" method="POST" action="/signup">
... Your Form ...
</form>
```

Comment: Sure ;) let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `.href` there is a *property* of `window.location` that you can get/set, not a function in itself (from the script-writer's point of view). Try this instead:

```
window.location.href = data.url;
```